# how eq(0) works with DOM

Tags: jquery

I want to know in below case will the browser stop traversing the DOM after getting the first .myclass

```
   $(".myclass").eq(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe so.

```
$(".myclass")
```

Will return a jQuery object that (behind the scenes) contains an array of all matching DOM elements.

You are then calling a method on that object to return the first element.

If you want to avoid this, you need your selector to only select one element. Take a look at the documentation for selectors:

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors

Try this instead:

```
$(".myclass:first").eq(0)
```

Comment: Note that in practice this will actually slow it down in recent browsers! This is because `:first` isn't a standard CSS selector, so jQuery won't be able to pass the work off the the new Selectors-API function `document.querySelectorAll`, and will have to fall back to the usual native-JavaScript ‘Sizzle’ selector library. The fastest solution would be to use `document.querySelector` (without the `All`) which gets just one element. However there is currently no jQuery integration for this method. You could sniff for it and fall back to jQuery, but it's probably a premature optimisation.

Comment: Does jQuery use this API now? In my experience, selecting by class (for large documents, at least) is slow anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No. In your example, the browser will fetch all the elements with class `myclass`. Then you apply a filter for the first element.

You might be able to call `.end()` after your `.eq(0)` to get the whole elements back.

You need the *selector* `eq`, like in the following example `$(".myclass:eq(0)")`.